# List most common occurring games between friends

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I just started learning mongodb so my pick on the queries is not really good at the moment.
So I will get straight to the problem. Following is my document for every user

```
{
    id:"14198959",
    user_name:"kikStart2X"
    friends:[
                {
                    friend_id:"1419897878",
                    friend_name:"nitpick",
                    profile_picture:"some image data",
                },
                {
                        friend_id:"14198848418",
                        friend_name:"applePie",
                        profile_picture:"some image data",
                }, //etc
            ],
    games:[
            {
                game_id:"1" , 
                game_name:"Bunny Hop"
            },
            {
               game_id:"2" , 
               game_name:"Racing cars",
            },
          ],
}
```

Now the collection has all the documents with same structure

1) friends array represents the users that are my friends

2) games array represents the games that I have played

My friends would have the same document structure with games array containing the games they have played

What I want is to list most common games between me and my friends in ascending/descending or any order.

The result should look like the following

```
{
    result:
    [
        {
            game_id:"1" , 
            game_name:"Bunny Hop",
            friends:
            [
                {
                        friend_id:"1419897878",
                        friend_name:"nitpick",
                        profile_picture:"some image data",
                },
                {
                        friend_id:"14198848418",
                        friend_name:"applePie",
                        profile_picture:"some image data",
                },

            ]
        },
        {
            game_id:"2" , 
            game_name:"Racing cars",
            friends:
            [
                {
                        friend_id:"71615343",
                        friend_name:"samuel",
                        profile_picture:"some image data",
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I know this is a bit tough to achieve but I don't know how to do it and have searched the internet for hours.
Thanks in advance to all you MongoDB champs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query.

The query will `$unwind` `friends` array followed up with `$lookup` for each friends games.

Next step is `$unwind` `friendsgames` followed by comparison using `$setIntersection` in `$project` stage to find the common games between the input document `games` and each of `friendsgames`.

Final step is to `$group` by `games` to collect `friends` with same games.

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
   { $unwind:"$friends" },     
   {
      $lookup: {
         from: collectionname,
         localField: "friends.friend_id",
         foreignField: "id",
         as: "friendsgames"
        }
   },
   { $unwind:"$friendsgames" },
   { $project:{commongames:{$setIntersection:["$games", "$friendsgames.games"]}, friends:1  }},
   { $unwind:"$commongames" },
   { $group:{_id:"$commongames", friends:{$push:"$friends"} } }    
] )
```

Comment: Where does it specify to look through my (any user's) friends only!

Comment: `localField: "friends.friend_id",` this part in the lookup takes care of that

Comment: M sorry I'm a bit confused!
i have an _id lets say ObjectId("454654654647") and I send that Id to mongodb to get the most common occuring games between me and my friends. So how would it look only in betwwen me and my friends only. Your solution is 90% correct but I dont see any restriction in specifying to look between users who are only my friend!

Comment: Np. You need to add `$match` stage at the top of the pipeline. Something like `$match:{_id:your_id}`. This will bring the common games between you (_id) and the list of friends (friends.friend_id) for that _id.

Comment: Haha I exactly did the same thing. Just wanted to make sure I am right! Thanks veeram. I am accepting it as answer. One last thing is it optimised.?I mean It wont slow down on big chunk of data because of $unwind!

Comment: Thanks. You are right!. It should not really make a lot of difference as you are doing a $match followed by $unwind.